# I wrote a SQL Query but not Run,WHY?

Tags: sql

Current Table

```
EmployeeID  CompanyID   EmployeeCode    EmployeeName
    1001        C001         11919     ABC
    1002        C001         10974         PQR
    1003        C001         11890     XYZ
    1004        C001         11621     LMN
```

Query like this...

```
     DECLARE @Empid VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @Empid= COALESCE(@Empid +',','')+''''+EmployeeID+'''' FROM cmsEmployee WHERE employeeCode IN('11919','10974','11890','11621' )
print @Empid
SELECT * FROM cmsEmployee WHERE EmployeeID IN( @Empid)
```

This Not working,Why?

Answer (score 3):

It is not working because you can't put a single string into the `in` clause and expect the engine to parse that.

You can only put in there multiple single values like you did when you used it in the first query.

```
where id in ('1','2')  -- works beause that are two SEPERATE values
where id in ('1,2')    -- works not because it is ONE string
```

Comment: Dear, print @Empid o/p is like ..a comma separated values, if doubt then first run this.

Comment: Look at my example closely. then you will understand. No matter how many quotes you insert in the string:  `@Empid` is ONE string.

Answer (score 0):

If you write a direct query that consists of multiple sections, you should not forget to add GO to execute each section.

```
Select ... 
GO
Print ... 
GO
Select ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are in SQL Server you likely need to use dynamic sql; that needs you to build your query up as a string then execute it when its complete

Change your empid declaration to

```
  DECLARE @Empid VARCHAR(MAX) = 'SELECT * FROM cmsEmployee WHERE EmployeeID IN( '
```

When you have selected it add a close bracket (you could build the string up in steps if you want to.)

```
select @empid = @empid + ')'
```

If you take your print statement it should run when you have it right; to run it in your code

```
exec sp_exectutesql @empID
```

Comment: Ya its working, But I want to RUN this query without using EXEC  then HOW ?

Comment: How are you getting your parameters into the query in the first place?  You could split them put them in a temp table and join to it