# TRIM mysql values not interpreted as string in outer query

Tags: mysql, trim

Consider the following query

```
select * from games 
where game_id in 
(
  SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT games FROM `users_games` WHERE `email`=1656366
  ))
)
```

The first inner query

```
SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM 
(
  SELECT games FROM `users_games` WHERE `email`=1656366
))`
```

returns `7497251,7497252,7497255,7497321,7497326,7497339,7497340,7497364,8178978`

But the total query returns data for only the row with `game_id = 7497251`. Why is it so? If i directly give the result of the inner TRIM query into the outer query, I get the desired result. Can anyone please explain why?

Comment: Read this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19465469/575376

Comment: It returns a comma separated string? You add one value to that string everytime a user plays a game?

Comment: @juergen d - i read d link and ur answer.So what is the solution here?Breaking it up into two queries,thts d only solution?

Comment: i need to count the no of games.I was planning to later replace * with count(game_id)

Comment: The only proper solution would be to change your database schema. Read about normalization. Comma separated values in one column are an absolute no go.

Comment: That is not possible now. :(

Comment: @MayurBuragohain. `SELECT games FROM users_games WHERE email=1656366` returns only one row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FIND_IN_SET()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) should work.

```
select * from games 
where find_in_set(game_id, 
(
  SELECT TRIM(LEADING ',' FROM 
  ( 
    SELECT games FROM `users_games` WHERE `email`=1656366
  ))
)) > 0
```

But as @fancyPants said:

### Never store multiple values in one column!